# How to get with preg_match_all only the number inside brackets

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to get with `preg_match_all` from the following:

```
[['p0',-1,[1,5,6,7,9,10],[['Text','ACER'],['Value','19'],['NavigateUrl','m-19-acer.aspx'],['Look-RightIconUrl','arrow.gif'],['Look-RightIconWidth','15']]]
```

only the number inside the brackets. That is `1,5,6,7,9,10` or:

```
['p1',0,[2,3,4],[['Text','NOTEBOOK'],['Value','87'],['NavigateUrl','m-87-notebook.aspx'],['Look-RightIconUrl','arrow.gif'],['Look-RightIconWidth','15']]],['p2',1,[],[['Text','MONITOR >11"'],['Value','125'],['NavigateUrl','m-125-monitor-11.aspx']]],
```

That is: `2,3,4`.

I'm something missing with this pattern I use `/(\d{1,})(,|\])/`. Can not get the 1st number correct, sometimes the last, sometimes I get more numbers

Comment: Is it always in that format?

Comment: Unfortunately, I found out today that I also have brackets with one number inside [234] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one:  `/\[[0-9,]+\]/`. Suppose it will work

Comment: Yes it works but would like to get each number in a array . For example this gives
 0 => 
  array (
    0 => '[2,3,4]',
but would like to get 
1 => 
  array (
    0 => '2',
    1 => '3',
    2 => '4',

Comment: you can iterate through matches and simply explode it on coma

Comment: Yes, you are correct , sometimes I struggle to find an answer and just an explode in this case is enough . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

preg_match_all by itself is not going to give you what you need.  You could start with a preg_match_all such as:

```
preg_match_all("/\[((\d,)+\d)\]/",$string,$matches);
```

The above will give you in `$matches[1]` an array of the full strings of digits still separated by commas.  In your second example it would consist of

```
var_dump($matches[1]);
arrray(1) { [0] => string(5) "2,3,4" }
```

You can then consolidate the elements of that array using join/implode as:

```
$all_matches = implode(',',$matches[1]);
```

In both of the examples you provided, this will do nothing, but should you have a case where there a multiple bracketed all digit elements, it will consolidate them all together (this may or may not be what you actually want).

You can then get the individual digit items using split

```
$individual_matches = split(',',$all_matches);
```

This will give you an array of `1,5,6,7,9,10` in your first example or `2,3,4` in your second example.  Obviously if you wanted to keep multiple matches separate, you could simply loop through the original array splitting each time:

```
$all_matches = $matches[1];
foreach ( $all_matches as $key => $value ) { 
    $all_matches[$key] = split(',',$all_matches[$key]);
}
```

This will give you an array of arrays where each 1st level represents the groups of bracketed numbers and the second level is the individual numbers split out of the group.

Comment: Note that the first (accepted) answer above will actually always produce an incorrect result because it will exclude the final number in the series, so in the first example it would leave out the 10 and in the second would leave out the 4 because it expects a comma after every number.

Comment: Nope, comma is part of the character class, so it is optional, anyway nice answer from your side

Comment: I think @Robert this answer isn't quit correct. I can not get any result . I changed it to /\[((\d{1,},)+\d{1,})\]/ ,and it is working. Unfortunately, I found out today that I also have brackets with one number inside [234] , so then this answer isn't working at all. Any way I used a compination solution  of  Maxim Shoustin regarding the pattern and the exploid method to get the rest. Thanks